# How to get rid of spam forever?

Tags: spam

I would like to know how I can permanently remove spam from my client's site. It was so bad that the registration page for new users to sign up was disabled and I am trying to enable it again but it seems that the file for it is hidden. If it can't be removed permanently, how can I reduce the spam?

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you are getting a lot of 'people' signing up to your website?

Here are two ways you could help reduce Spam (Has helped a lot for me):

1. Keep an eye on your access_log within the server.  If you see the same IP addresses accessing your website, block them.
2. Require sign-ups to have to verify their credentials by clicking on a 'Confirm' link that is sent to their email address.

Hope this is a good start in your battle against Spam!

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give it a try. I think that so many people were signing up that they could leave the  spam

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help!  Let me know how you get on!  Good luck with the website! :-)

Comment: I was able to get rid of the spam and get alerts within the dashboard of how many spams were trying to come through. Thanks so much for your help! Now I'm dealing with more dilemmas but thats a whole nother story\ :(

Comment: Not a problem.  Glad I could be of help.  If you feel your question has been resolved, could you spare a moment to accept my answer so that others can see this as a potential solution for their query.  Look forward to seeing your other questions! Good luck with your website! :-)